# Sorting a list of cards

Tags: haskell

I have a card datatype:

```
data Card = Card Rank
   deriving (Ord)
```

where i can create numbered cards in an array denoted by:

```
mycard = [Card 1,Card 7, Card 3]
```

I'm now trying to sort the cards based on their rank in descending order particularly using quick sort. Hence i would get

```
[Card 7, Card 3, Card 1]
```

I wrote:

```
quicksort :: [Card] -> [Card]  
quicksort [] = []  
quicksort (x:xs) =   
    let smallerSorted = quicksort [a | a <- xs, a <= x !! 1]  #compare at index 1 which is the rank
        biggerSorted = quicksort [a | a <- xs, a > x !! 1] #compare at index 1 which is the rank 
    in  smallerSorted ++ [x] ++ biggerSorted
```

But I'm getting an error saying

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘[Card]’ with actual type ‘Card’
• In the first argument of ‘(!!)’, namely ‘x’
  In the second argument of ‘(>)’, namely ‘x !! 1’
  In the expression: a > x !! 1
```

Comment: Haskell comments are written with `-- comment`, not `#comment`.

Comment: That's not array, it's a list.

Answer (score 2):

`x` is a single Card, and you're trying to index it with `x !! 1`. The first argument of `!!` must be a list (`[Card]`), but you supplied a `Card` instead, hence the error.

I think you should compare with just `x`.

Answer (score 1):

The error is pointing out that you're trying to perform list-indexing (`!!`) on a `Card`, and a `Card` isn't a list.

It looks like you're trying to use `!!` to extract the rank from a `Card`, possibly under the assumption that `Card` is index 0, and the `Rank` index 1.
That's not something you can do, and not at all how anything works.

Since you've derived `Ord`, you can simply compare two `Card`s:

```
[a | a <- xs, a <= x]
```

If you hadn't derived `Ord`, you could have defined your own "extractor":

```
rank (Card r) = r

...

[a | a <- xs, rank a <= rank x]
```